# MapView Camera position not being updated

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple MapView in a fragment. This is my code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

MapView m;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
            false);

    m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    m.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(36.16,-86.78) , 14);
            googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

        }
    });

    return v;
}}
```

However, when I run the app, the camera position is still always stuck at the default location: the global view centered on Africa. Any help would be appreciated. In addition, when I click back onto the tab that loads this fragment, it always returns to the default view, not one that I have changed.

Comment: Update: works now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(36.16,-86.78)).zoom(14).build();
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
    googleMap.moveCamera(update);
```